# What language is this in?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

What language is this in? It's interspersed in an html.erb file that I have to update, but it doesn't look like Ruby.

```
{#if $T.location[0].city}{$T.location[0].city}, {#/if}{#if $T.location[0].state}{$T.location[0].state}{#/if}
```

It looks like it could be this template: http://jtemplates.tpython.com/.
But I couldn't find {# template MAIN} anywhere in the codebase.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is .tpl files? php, web design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808294/what-is-tpl-files-php-web-design)

Comment: .tpl - it's a template. could be a standard templating engine, or something custom. no real way to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808294/what-is-tpl-files-php-web-design), it's probably a [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) file. Beyond that, I couldn't tell you.