# PHP - replacing select by radio button

Tags: php, html, testlink

Use TestLink 1.9.14 for managing the testing and implementation of the page there is the implementation status of select , I want to change the select by a radio button , as pictured below.
I do not know which or what files you need to change to effect this change .

the system is in php and has TPL files , of which I do not Fawn knowledge , I am afraid to move and end up damaging some functionality.

[image: Testlink]

```
<div class="resultBox">
          {if $args_save_type == 'bulk'}
            {foreach key=verbose_status item=locale_status from=$tlCfg->results.status_label_for_exec_ui}
                              <input type="radio" {$args_input_enable_mgmt} name="{$radio_id_prefix}[{$args_tcversion_id}]" 
                              id="{$radio_id_prefix}_{$args_tcversion_id}_{$ResultsStatusCode.$verbose_status}" 
                                value="{$ResultsStatusCode.$verbose_status}"
                                            onclick="javascript:set_combo_group('execSetResults','status_','{$ResultsStatusCode.$verbose_status}');"
                                {if $verbose_status eq $tlCfg->results.default_status}
                                    checked="checked" 
                                {/if} /> &nbsp;{lang_get s=$locale_status}<br />
                      {/foreach}
          {else}
            {$args_labels.test_exec_result}&nbsp;
            <select name="statusSingle[{$tcversion_id}]" id="statusSingle_{$tcversion_id}">
            {html_options options=$gui->execStatusValues}
            </select>
          {/if}
          </div>
```

Comment: Question not clear!!

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to change a select option box to a radio list.

old code would be:

```
<select>
<option value="Nao Exectute">Nao Exectute<option>
<option value="Passou">Passou<option>
<option value="Others">others<option>
</select>
```

New code would be:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioList" id="radioList01" value="Nao Exectute"><label for="radioList01">Nao Exectute</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="radioList" id="radioList02" value="Passou"><label for="radioList02">Passou</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="radioList" id="radioList03" value="Others"><label for="radioList03">Others</label><br />
```

That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: the system is in php and has TPL files , of which I do not Fawn knowledge , I am afraid to move and end up damaging some functionality.
added the source code in question

Comment: Oh...  Well in that case, I recommend reading this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808294/what-is-tpl-files-php-web-design  That may better explain how to edit the files.  But my answer here, essentially is what you'd need to do, in the raw sense.