# what does this {HotDeail} mean in php?

Tags: php

My friend has given me to redesign his website and the code looks like this. The code has .tpl extension. I just want to know what does that {HotDeail} means?[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is .tpl files? php, web design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808294/what-is-tpl-files-php-web-design)

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is a variable from backend

**Comment related update:**

A common goal among experienced web developers is to develop and deploy applications that are flexible and easily maintainable. An important consideration in reaching this goal is the separation of business logic from presentation logic. Developers use web template systems (with varying degrees of success) to maintain this separation

**P.S.** Read more [template engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system) and [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: can u elaborate it little bit more?

Comment: Added some detailes in my answer

Comment: thank u very much for your effort but where are the actual code located for {HotDeail}

Comment: in Controllers, if you are familiar with php (for example) {HotDeail} is analogue <?php echo $HotDeail; ?>