# Do I have to change any settings of server for php code blocks?

Tags: php, html, codeblocks

I have php installed (via zpanel) in my windows 7 pc and I want to echo php variable using codeblocks by the following way:

```
<?php
$myname = 'Mr. Arnold';
?>
//in html
my name is {$myname}
```

is it possible to echo the variable it in html? Actually I intend to create a template using html and php. So I want to echo it in html format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<?php
$myname = 'Mr. Arnold';
echo "my name is {$myname}";
?>
```

Comment: I know that will be worked. But I found in some .tpl files that it is written in html format using codeblocks. That's why I am asking.

Comment: Refer attached query which gives more idea on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808294/what-is-tpl-files-php-web-design

Answer (score 1):

In the PHP Block Quoted Example you have to follow the procedure of how you need to echo it so that it will display the Data from that.

**PHP Method:**

```
<?php
$myname = "Mr. Arnold";
echo "my name is {$myname}";
?>
```

**HTML method:**

```
<?php
$myname = "Mr. Arnold";
?>
HTML:
my name is <?php echo $myname; ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if you have a VPS server than you can make a changes in php.ini file. but if you don't have a VPS server than make .user.ini file or php.ini and upload it in your Web hosting root folder. Than may be it will work.

Comment: I have my own server installed in windows 7 and I can edit php.ini file. Please tell me which line in php.ini should be edited for the desired purpose?