# Implementing a PSD design into a .tpl website

Tags: task-parallel-library, photoshop

I am new to the whole web design business so I started to design websites using Photoshop. After my first design project I've sent the designs to the developer who then asked me to implement the design into the old site and cut it up. So he gave me a username and password to the server in which the site is being stored. The whole website uses .tpl files and I have no idea how to even start implementing the design. Do I have to start from scratch? Can I use photoshop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is .tpl files? php, web design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808294/what-is-tpl-files-php-web-design)

Comment: I need to know how to get started from scratch, from psd to the website itself.